# dynamic button created in fragment disappears after re-entering the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button, otto

I have two classes. One extends FragmentActivity (MainActivity.java) and the other extends Fragment (HomeFragment.java). **What I want is to create an image button in MainActivity and put it in home_fragment.xml and then update HomeFragment.java so that my imagebutton is permanently in the layout.** Right now, I have a button, and add it to home_fragment.xml, and that works fine, but then if I leave that fragment and return back to it (through a button click), the button disappears.

Here is a picture of my interface. Where home_fragment is the white space with the "DriveDroid" button inside. And it is initiated when I click "Button 1". If I click button 2, 3, or 4 a different fragment is activated and if I go back to "Button 1", which opens home_fragment.xml, then the "DriveDroid" button is gone.

[image]

MainActivity is running a separate thread and listening on a port for an incoming image. Once it gets this image it creates an imagebutton with the image as the background. It adds this image button to an xml layout (home_fragment). This is all working correctly and this is the code I have for MainActivity:

```
private void RepeatTask()
{
  repeatTaskThread = new Thread()
  {
     public void run()
     {
        while (true)
        {


           try {


              System.out.println("TRY_1");

              Socket socket = new Socket("72.120.55.34", 5050);

              // Get data sent through socket
              DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

              System.out.println("DataInputStream Started");

              // read data that got sent
              String applicationName = DIS.readUTF();


              // read array data for bitmap

              int len = DIS.readInt();
              byte[] data = new byte[len];

              DIS.readFully(data, 0, data.length);


               Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
               final Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);



              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    Log.d("tag_name", "Try_2");


                    ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
                    //btn.setId(1);
                    btn.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
                    Log.d("tag_name", "Create Button" + btn);

                    ViewGroup RelativeLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.home_fragment);
                    btn.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    RelativeLayout.addView(btn);
                    Log.d("tag_name", "Button Added to View" + RelativeLayout);


                    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {



                       }
                    });


                 }
              });



              socket.close();


           } catch (Exception e) {


              System.out.println("Exception is "+e.toString());

           }



           try
           {
              // Sleep for 5 seconds
               Thread.sleep(5000);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
     };
  };
  repeatTaskThread.start();
}
```

How can I get this image button to update in HomeFragment? And is this even what I should be doing? I just need my image button to now always appear whenever other parts of my code call on HomeFragment.

Here is how HomeFragment is called when Button1 is pushed (this code is in another fragment):

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_menu, container, false);

    // get home image button
    ImageButton Button1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnHOME);
    // button listener
    Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @MethnaniBilel do you know how I can use otto to update my HomeFragment with my dynamic button?

Comment: So the main problem is that the button disappears. Where do you navigate from your fragment? How do you start this component that you navigate to? Will need to see the fragment code for this.

Comment: @varunkr I updated my question to show my problem more clearly and also show how I initiate HomeFragment. I didn't post my code for HomeFragment because I think the only relevant thing happening in that code is that onCreateView() I am inflating home_fragment.xml

Comment: The problem is obvious. On clicking the button1 you are creating a new instance of the fragment. SO essentially the old instance that you created and to which you added the imageButton is now gone. Your other question about the GridAdapter probably has this issue as well as I commented. You must understand what an instance it and what a new instance creation means. You basiaclly created your fragment and added the imageButton, then after some navigation you again re-create your fragment. So you are creating a new fragment. No doubt it will not contain the button.

Comment: So, am I creating a new HomeFragment when I call "ft.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();" and it's because I am saying "NEW" HomeFragment? I guess I did not learn this correctly, but I should be able to open it another way and anything added to HomeFragment will remain?

Comment: Yes obviously it is a new fragment !! That is exactly what the term new means, creating a new instance !! Of course there is a way !